# How to change the value of custom fields (\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\Index.cshtml.c)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

(Environment: Visual Studio 2019 v16.4.3)

I create a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application" with the following options

1. ASP.Net Core 3.1
2. Angular
3. Authentication of Individual User Account (with "Store user accounts in-app", the only option)

Then  I did the following to add all the scaffolded items.

- From Solution Explorer, right-click on the project > Add > New Scaffolded Item
- Added new fields `FirstName` and `LastName` in the class `ApplicationUser` and updated the code to enable the registration with the new fields. The first name and last name can be saved to the database after registration.

Now I need to modify the code to enable the user to modify the customized fields `FirstName` and `LastName`. The following shows the class (I made some changes for `FirstName` and `LastName`). In the method `OnPostAsync()`, it calls `_userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber)` to change the values.  How to define `_userManager.SetFistNameAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber)` and `_userManager.SetLastNameAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber)`?

**\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\Index.cshtml.cs**

```
public partial class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public IndexModel(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    private async Task LoadAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
        var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

        Username = userName;

        Input = new InputModel
        {
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName
        };
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        await LoadAsync(user);
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await LoadAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }

        var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
        if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
        {
            var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);
            if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
            {
                var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred setting phone number for user with ID '{userId}'.");
            }
        }

        await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've worked with the ASP.NET Core Identity stuff, but I believe you update your custom user object from here (GetUserAsync should return your custom `ApplicationUser` class):

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
user.LastName = Input.LastName;
```

Then call _userManager.UpdateAsync(user):

```
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

Comment: Curiously, why it has a predefined `SetPhoneNumberAsync()` for phone number?

Comment: I believe since the identity system comes with two-factor authentication, with phone being one method, it is built in.