# Errors when scaffolding identity in ASP.NET core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am trying to add custom fields, but I cannot find any decent documentation on the subject, and whenever I try, I end up with a plethora of errors relating to ApplicationDBContext.cs. How would I add custom fields to the database and add them to the sign-up screen? I am starting from a Blazor Server template with Individual Accounts.

Comment: A code sample would be helpful

Comment: You probably looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033173/how-to-change-the-value-of-custom-fields-areas-identity-pages-account-manage-i). The detail steps to customize could be found in [Customize the model document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-the-model).

Comment: I attempted that, and got errors: https://pastebin.com/LWcWxeAy

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new class that extends `ApplicationUser` and add custom properties there.

Comment: I have gotten to that point, the point I am stuck at is the scaffolding. I am using Visual Studio, if that helps

Comment: Did you create new migration? What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: I did create a migration. Here is the output of `dotnet build` after scaffolding Register.cshtml: https://pastebin.com/LWcWxeAy